# how to pick specific string value using regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

let's say i have this value = how/to/pick/**specific_string**/value/using/regex/in/javascript/01;

how can i pick this text : specific_string

when i make looping this array

```
var data = : [

{ ref_no : "let/me/farid03/h/01" },
{ ref_no : "let/me/farid02/h/02" }

];
```

how can i predict and pick one value using regex.

. so when looped, it will give me farid03 and farid02

i death of code already. i really need some help for this. thank you :)

Comment: Could you pls be a bit more specific? What is the value you want? From where do you want it? Can you give us some example?

Comment: var extract = value.split('/')[3] //make the array and get the text using index

Comment: For the time being this seems to answer your question, but I don't think it's what you want: https://regex101.com/r/gW6xJ5/1

Comment: i means, i want to clear all string between /<>/

only give that bold string

Comment: @kpsingh u such amazing!!!!. thank you!!. it work!! love yaaa

Comment: @farid-blaster thanks. i placed this code as an answer for your question.

Comment: @kpsingh yeah sure! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = [
  { ref_no:"let/me/farid03/h/01" },
  { ref_no:"let/me/farid02/h/02" }
];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   alert(data[i].ref_no.split('/')[2]);
}
```